Webpack hot module replacement fully reloads page in response to css style changes, fully resetting application state
What is wrong with my config? Why doesn't HMR work as specified?
I want web-dev-server to hot module replacement, in response to project changes not fully refresh i.e liveReload. This is disruptive to my workflow as, when my application state resets while i'm working on styling, I have to go through an entire e2e flow just to see the effects of my change.
The webpack-dev-server does not function along with its API specifications. Despite my config being set to devServer.hot, webpack liveReloads to every file change, be it css, js or html.
According to the Webpack-dev-servers documentation, for liveReload to take effect, devServer.hot must be disabled.

By default, the dev-server will reload/refresh the page when file changes are detected. devServer.hot option must be disabled or devServer.watchFiles option must be enabled in order for liveReload to take effect. Disable devServer.liveReload by setting it to false:

source
So liveReload shouldn't even be working yet somehow it supercedes HMR.
This is my webpack config
webpack.dev.js
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');
const common = require('./webpack.common');

module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  devServer: {
    static: './src',
    port: 8080,
    hot: true,

    // watchFiles: ['src/*.html'],
  },
});

webpack.common.js:
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const dotEnv = require('dotenv-webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    index: './src/index.ts',
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
  },

  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    clean: true,
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
        type: 'asset/resource',
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/app.html'),
    }),
    new dotEnv(),
  ],
};


The only thing that has worked, is setting liveReload to false. However, that makes it so that I have to manually reload html changes as HMR does not seem to function for html.
